# Cram's rule vs Felkin Anh's model

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereoselectivity, c-x-addition

I am getting two different products based on the Cram and Felkin-Anh models as shown in the diagram. Any explanation?
[image: reaction schemes illustrating difference]

Comment: If they always gave the same answer, we wouldn't need two models...

Comment: @Zhe it’s actually Anh :-)

Comment: @orthocresol [face palm]

Comment: @orthocresol Of all the references in the Wikipedia article on asymmetric induction to "Anh," one of them was misspelled and for whatever reason, that's the one that I found on my search. Obviously, the correct thing to do was not to fix it here but to fix it in Wikipedia...

Comment: @Zhe, I had to check to be sure (when I was making my first comment), and I found plenty of websites with Ahn, so it seems pretty common...

Comment: The Newman projection you have used for the Felkin-Anh model is -the one giving minor diastereomer. Attack on the less hindered side on the appropriate Newman projection would give the same product as the cram model.